# Extracting public key from Raw Binary Bytes of RSA 512

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, rsa

This is what I have in the Raw Binary file,

```
\x99\x02\xc4\xa6k\x1f\xf7c\x92\x91\x9e{\xbc5\xd5\x1aQ(\xb9\xda\x03\xe11\xb4\x89\xd5\xed\x01\xc1\xd0u\xfcL\x13\x9a\x99R\xe9\xa3\xb0@\xd9\x84!\x9aJ\xef\rB\x1fk\x8f\x9cy\xe1\xc3\xc3Z!\x8e\xcb\xa5M\xc9\x01\x00\x01'
```

I want to create a public RSA key to verify a digital signature. I've been looking for help and would appreciate if anyone could help me out. 
Came across someone saying that the exponent is after the RSA tag but how do I find that in this file?

Comment: What is the format, origin, purpose, context of the raw binary file you are dealing with?

Comment: It's a .bin file, it is supposed to have the public key, modulus and exponent combined
https://i.imgur.com/lAHupat.png

Comment: The extension is only marginally helpful. The second part of the comment was already implicitly clear. Please give more information on format, origin, purpose, context. What software created it? Does it follow any standards? Do you have any other information on the format of the file?

Comment: What kind of a mixture of what seems hexadecimal representation and "{", "Q(", "@", "!", "J", "k", "y".  Also "\rB" seems an exception to the other representations, I miss a "xdigits". I think that even what you show here is unclean and contains copy-paste errors or typos.

Comment: The notation is suitable for a python byte string enclosed by b'', i.e. `b'\x99\x02\xc4\xa6k\x1f\xf7...\xc9\x01\x00\x01'`. And it is possible that the first 64 bytes are the modulus and the last 3 are the exponent.

Comment: @JamesKPolk My small Java thingamajiggy that I wrote to decode these horrible encoded byte array strings says that it is 68 bytes instead of 67 bytes, which you would expect. There doesn't seem to be a separator, and both the first and last byte before the exponent is 1) larger than 0x80 and 2) odd. So I'm not sure if the modulus is actually 512 or 520 bit and that it is big or little endian encoding.